# Blank pop up window instead of camera image

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, ros-hydro, openni.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using ros Hydro with Kinect, but when I try to open the kinect camera with any of the commands below I get a blank (empty) pop up window.

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color

rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_mono

rosrun image_view disparity_view image:=/camera/depth/disparity

rosrun image_view disparity_view image:=/camera/depth_registered/disparity
```

Well...I check `rostopic hz image_view` and get:

```
WARNING: topic [/image_view] does not appear to be published yet (and the same message for /disparity_view)
```

Soo I check the `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch` log and found many warnings, process died and FATAL as can be seem below:

```
started roslaunch server http://ubuntu:38154/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /camera/camera_nodelet_manager/num_worker_threads
 * /camera/depth_rectify_depth/interpolation
 * /camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth/interpolation
 * /camera/disparity_depth/max_range
 * /camera/disparity_depth/min_range
 * /camera/disparity_registered_hw/max_range
 * /camera/disparity_registered_hw/min_range
 * /camera/disparity_registered_sw/max_range
 * /camera/disparity_registered_sw/min_range
 * /camera/driver/depth_camera_info_url
 * /camera/driver/depth_frame_id
 * /camera/driver/depth_registration
 * /camera/driver/device_id
 * /camera/driver/rgb_camera_info_url
 * /camera/driver/rgb_frame_id
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion

NODES
  /camera/
    camera_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    debayer (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_metric (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_metric_rect (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_points (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    depth_registered_rectify_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_depth (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_registered_hw (nodelet/nodelet)
    disparity_registered_sw (nodelet/nodelet)
    driver (nodelet/nodelet)
    points_xyzrgb_hw_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
    points_xyzrgb_sw_registered (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_color (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_ir (nodelet/nodelet)
    rectify_mono (nodelet/nodelet)
    register_depth_rgb (nodelet/nodelet)
  /
    camera_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-1]: started with pid [3232]
process[camera/driver-2]: started with pid [3233]
process[camera/debayer-3]: started with pid [3234]
process[camera/rectify_mono-4]: started with pid [3241]
process[camera/rectify_color-5]: started with pid [3281]
process[camera/rectify_ir-6]: started with pid [3310]
[ INFO] [1408885127.360993852]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
process[camera/depth_rectify_depth-7]: started with pid [3365]
process[camera/depth_metric_rect-8]: started with pid [3390]
process[camera/depth_metric-9]: started with pid [3404]
process[camera/depth_points-10]: started with pid [3418]
process[camera/register_depth_rgb-11]: started with pid [3432]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-12]: started with pid [3446]
process[camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth-13]: started with pid [3460]
process[camera/points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-14]: started with pid [3474]
process[camera/disparity_depth-15]: started with pid [3488]
process[camera/disparity_registered_sw-16]: started with pid [3502]
process[camera/disparity_registered_hw-17]: started with pid [3516]
process[camera_base_link-18]: started with pid [3539]
process[camera_base_link1-19]: started with pid [3540]
process[camera_base_link2-20]: started with pid [3561]
process[camera_base_link3-21]: started with pid [3572]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'openni_wrapper::OpenNIException'
  what():  unsigned int openni_wrapper::OpenNIDriver::updateDeviceList() @ /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-openni-camera-1.9.2-0precise-20140720-0503/src/openni_driver.cpp @ 125 : enumerating image nodes failed. Reason: One or more of the following nodes could not be enumerated:

Image: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.1.0.41: Device is in safe mode. Cannot start any stream!

[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-1] process has died [pid 3232, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=camera_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-camera_nodelet_manager-1.log].
log file: /home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-camera_nodelet_manager-1*.log
[FATAL] [1408885141.085922349]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1408885141.086503987]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1408885141.087275454]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1408885141.087514940]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1408885141.088301075]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1408885141.089200491]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1408885141.089199723]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1408885141.089904073]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1408885141.089974054]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1408885141.090742030]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1408885141.091620075]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1408885141.092166023]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1408885141.092412563]: Service call failed!
[FATAL] [1408885141.092465572]: Service call failed!
[camera/depth_points-10] process has died [pid 3418, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyz camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_rect:=depth/image_rect_raw points:=depth/points __name:=depth_points __log:=/home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-depth_points-10.log].
log file: /home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-depth_points-10*.log
[camera/register_depth_rgb-11] process has died [pid 3432, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/register camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond rgb/camera_info:=rgb/camera_info depth/camera_info:=depth/camera_info depth/image_rect:=depth/image_rect_raw depth_registered/image_rect:=depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw __name:=register_depth_rgb __log:=/home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-register_depth_rgb-11.log].
log file: /home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-register_depth_rgb-11*.log
[camera/points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-12] process has died [pid 3446, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond rgb/image_rect_color:=rgb/image_rect_color rgb/camera_info:=rgb/camera_info depth_registered/image_rect:=depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw depth_registered/points:=depth_registered/points __name:=points_xyzrgb_sw_registered __log:=/home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-12.log].
log file: /home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-12*.log
[camera/disparity_registered_sw-16] process has died [pid 3502, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/disparity camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond left/image_rect:=depth_registered/sw_registered/image_rect_raw right:=projector left/disparity:=depth_registered/disparity __name:=disparity_registered_sw __log:=/home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-disparity_registered_sw-16.log].
log file: /home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-disparity_registered_sw-16*.log
[camera/driver-2] process has died [pid 3233, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load openni_camera/driver camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond ir:=ir rgb:=rgb depth:=depth depth_registered:=depth_registered projector:=projector __name:=driver __log:=/home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-driver-2.log].
log file: /home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-driver-2*.log
[camera/debayer-3] process has died [pid 3234, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/debayer camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_raw:=rgb/image_raw image_mono:=rgb/image_mono image_color:=rgb/image_color __name:=debayer __log:=/home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-debayer-3.log].
log file: /home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-debayer-3*.log
[camera/rectify_color-5] process has died [pid 3281, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=rgb/image_color image_rect:=rgb/image_rect_color __name:=rectify_color __log:=/home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-rectify_color-5.log].
log file: /home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-rectify_color-5*.log
[camera/depth_rectify_depth-7] process has died [pid 3365, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=depth/image_raw image_rect:=depth/image_rect_raw __name:=depth_rectify_depth __log:=/home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-depth_rectify_depth-7.log].
log file: /home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-depth_rectify_depth-7*.log
[camera/depth_metric_rect-8] process has died [pid 3390, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/convert_metric camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_raw:=depth/image_rect_raw image:=depth/image_rect __name:=depth_metric_rect __log:=/home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-depth_metric_rect-8.log].
log file: /home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-depth_metric_rect-8*.log
[camera/depth_metric-9] process has died [pid 3404, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/convert_metric camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_raw:=depth/image_raw image:=depth/image __name:=depth_metric __log:=/home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-depth_metric-9.log].
log file: /home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-depth_metric-9*.log
[camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth-13] process has died [pid 3460, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load image_proc/rectify camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond image_mono:=depth_registered/image_raw image_rect:=depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw __name:=depth_registered_rectify_depth __log:=/home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-depth_registered_rectify_depth-13.log].
log file: /home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-depth_registered_rectify_depth-13*.log
[camera/points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-14] process has died [pid 3474, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/point_cloud_xyzrgb camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond rgb/image_rect_color:=rgb/image_rect_color rgb/camera_info:=rgb/camera_info depth_registered/image_rect:=depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw depth_registered/points:=depth_registered/points __name:=points_xyzrgb_hw_registered __log:=/home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-14.log].
log file: /home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-14*.log
[camera/disparity_registered_hw-17] process has died [pid 3516, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/disparity camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond left/image_rect:=depth_registered/hw_registered/image_rect_raw right:=projector left/disparity:=depth_registered/disparity __name:=disparity_registered_hw __log:=/home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-disparity_registered_hw-17.log].
log file: /home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-disparity_registered_hw-17*.log
[camera/disparity_depth-15] process has died [pid 3488, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load depth_image_proc/disparity camera_nodelet_manager --no-bond left/image_rect:=depth/image_rect_raw right:=projector left/disparity:=depth/disparity __name:=disparity_depth __log:=/home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-disparity_depth-15.log].
log file: /home/felipe/.ros/log/1cb03004-2b8e-11e4-8313-701a04a7b383/camera-disparity_depth-15*.log
```

I found some questions with problems that seems to be similar, but I didn't found a solution so far. Following the links of related problems:

- http://answers.ros.org/question/67198/image_view-displays-empty-gray-window/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/172643/device-is-in-safe-mode-cannot-start-any-stream/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/148901/primesensesensorv251041-device-is-in-safe-mode/
- http://answers.ros.org/question/11423/openni_kinect-dosent-publish-anything-in-the-topics-or-rviz/

I will appreciate any help!
Thanks in advance

(Btw...sorry any mistake this is my first question here)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191115/blank-pop-up-window-instead-of-camera-image/) by [fmartino](https://answers.ros.org/users/20076/fmartino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-24**:
I changed the formatting a bit. Please indent console output with 4 spaces on each line, that makes it easier to read.

**Comment by [SonOfDamage](https://answers.ros.org/users/21032/sonofdamage/) on 2014-12-05**:
Hey even I have a similar issue. image_view opens a blank image. My system runs indigo as opposed to your hydro, and uses a normal webcam connected. Anybody has a clue??

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-05**:
@SonOfDamage: since this is a hardware-specific issue and you're working with different hardware and drivers, your issue is probably different. I recommend asking a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't have a specific answer, but the key error to Google for is "Image: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.1.0.41: Device is in safe mode. Cannot start any stream!"

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0